# Не работает простеший пример с JSTL

Tags: jstl, java, веб-программирование

Код взял отсюда
http://www.apekshit.com/t/87/JSTL-Core-Tags

Подкачиваю зависимость через Мавен

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>jstl</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

В итоге получаю

${test}

Хотя ожидалалась фраза "JSTL Core Tags".
В чем может быть причина?

Comment: Вот этот пример сработал
http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-use-jstl-on-my-jsps.html
easy game)
Кто понял почему тут работает, а там нет, обьясните, пожалуйста

Answer (score 2):

Добавляем

```
 <%@ page isELIgnored="false" %>
```

и все работает

Comment: А что это за настройка?